# Downloading a file using PHP through the IDM (Internet Download Manager)

Tags: php, download, download-manager

I'm working on a web page where a user can download a file but only after accepting the license, so I made the process using `PHP` to check if the user checked the license and to not reveal the file's `URL`, the code works just fine as I wanted (downloading), **here is the code :**

```
$fileName = $_GET['AppName'] . " - Setup.exe";

$path = 'JO9E/' . $fileName;
$size = filesize($path);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');

if($file) {
    $_SESSION["TEMP"] = "nO";
    fpassthru($file);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
}
```

**But now my issue is :**

I have `IDM` (Internet Download Manager) installed on my computer, and when i want to download the file... `IDM` shows the download box to download the file, revealing the `PHP` file path, and **also it will not download the file** when i hit start download, it losses the connection.

Now i don't have a problem revealing the `PHP` file path since it will not download anything unless the user accepted the license and came from the correct web page, **but i want** at least the user to be able to download the file even if he had `IDM` installed, because at this setup if the user had `IDM` installed, he must turn of the integration functionality in `IDM` in order to download the file through the browser correctly.

---

**Hope someone can help me with this.**

Comment: should we know what IDM is ?

Comment: @smith IDM is a popular shortcut for a popular app which is **'Internet Download Manager'** to download files faster.

Comment: you really shouldn't have that echo after `fpassthru()`

Comment: You should not directly concatenate a `$_GET` parameter into a file path like that. You've given the internet a easy way to retrieve any readable file on your server.

Comment: @Sammitch That is a good point, but don't worry, this is not the full file, I tweaked it before posting it here ;) ...I've thought of that,  but thanks for pointing at this any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put a small instruction next to your download link with 
`right click and press Save As`

IDM browser extension catches all files with extensions that are selected in the IDM options.so it is on bowser level.